# Disable Auto Creation of Features

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, feature

Is there a was to disable to auto creation of Features in Visual Studio? Every time I add a new Element, it automatically creates Featurex. I have one solution, that every time I open it up, it creates 10 features, one for each List Instance. I want them all deployed via one single feature and I want to include them in the Manifest manually

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add/remove solution items from features in the design view of the feature. So, you could remove the list instances from features and add all list instances in to one feature and delete empty features.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231556.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231544.aspx

Comment: I know how to manually remove them from design view. The question was how to disable the auto creation of a feature when adding new elements such as a list instance